# EmitterProcessor - onNext or FluxSink

Tags: project-reactor

With an EmitterProcessor I can use `onNext` or `sink` to get a FluxSink and use that.

```
EmitterProcessor<Long> emitterProcessor = EmitterProcessor.create(100);

// Option 1  
emitterProcessor.onNext(1L);

// Option 2
FluxSink fluxSink = emitterProcessor.sink();
fluxSink.next(1L);
```

Is one better than the other, when should I use one over the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/) documentation (4.7.2), Do not use processor directly. Instead use Sink facade to emit the values.

`Sink.next` is thread safe using which you could emit values from multiple threads. onNext could cause issues. So, option 2 is correct.